# Is there a clone on a three element set which is not finitely generated?

Tags: universal-algebra

Let **3** be the three element set $\{0,1,2\}$. Is there a clone (in the sense of universal algebra) on **3** which is not finitely generated? I know that every clone on a two element set is finitely generated, so what about a three element set? And if the answer is yes, can someone exhibit a clone on **3** which is not finitely generated, along with the proof that it is not?

Comment: Yes: there are uncountably many clones on a three-element set, and only countably many finitely generated clones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f_n\colon \mathbf{3}^n\to \mathbf{3}$ be the operation defined by $f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=0$ whenever $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\neq (2,2,\ldots,2)$ and $f_n(2,2,\ldots,2)=1$.  The clone $\mathfrak{C}$ that is generated by $\{f_n\;|\; n\in \omega\}$ is not finitely generated.

Reason:

The operations $f_n$ are defined to have the properties that
(i) $f_n(\mathbf{3},\ldots,\mathbf{3})\subseteq \{0,1\}$ and (ii) $f_n(\mathbf{3},\ldots,\mathbf{3},\{0,1\},\mathbf{3},\ldots,\mathbf{3})\subseteq \{0\}$.
If you generate a clone on $\{0,1,2\}$ with these operations, all nonprojections in the clone will still have properties (i) and (ii).

The effect of this is that if you compose nonprojections of $\mathfrak{C}$, you almost always obtain an operation that is constant zero.
Explicitly, if $g, h\in \mathfrak{C}$ are nonprojections, then

$g(x_{1},\ldots,x_{j-1},h(y_{1},\ldots,y_{m}),x_{j+1}\ldots,x_{n})=0$

for any $j, m, n$ and any substitution of values to the variables. From this we derive that the operations in $\mathfrak{C}$ are the projections, the constant zero operation of each arity ($0(x_1,\ldots,x_n) =0$) and the operations obtained from the generating operations by variable manipulation (from $f_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, we can replace each variable $x_i$ with a variable $x_{i_j}$ to obtain $f_n(x_{j_1},\ldots,x_{j_n})$).

This is sufficient to imply that $\mathfrak{C}$ is not finitely generated. The subclone generated by any finite subset
$\{g_1,\ldots,g_m\}\subseteq \mathfrak{C}$ will not contain any $f_n$ if $n$ is greater than the arity of each of the $g_i$'s.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the same is true if we look at $$j_n: {\bf 3}^n\rightarrow{\bf 3}: \overline{x}\mapsto\begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{ if }\vert\{i: x_i\not=2\}\vert\le 1,\\
0 & \mbox{ otherwise},
\end{cases}$$ which additionally has the feature that no $j_n$ is in the clone generated by $\{j_m: m\not=n\}$. This latter feature lets us prove that there are continuum many clones on ${\bf 3}$ by looking at the clone generated by $\{j_n: n\in X\}$ for $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. Does that seem right? *(I add this only because it's weirdly hard to find an online proof of this uncountability!)*

Comment: (And to the OP, this tweak is needed since e.g. $f_1(x)=f_2(x,x)$.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I agree with what you have written.

Answer (score 3):

*Since comments are ephemeral, I'm making my footnote to Keith Kearnes' answer more permanent:*

If we modify the answer above slightly, we get an even stronger phenomenon. Let $$j_n:{\bf 3}^n\rightarrow{\bf 3}: (x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto\begin{cases}
1 & \mbox{ if }\vert\{i:x_i\not=2\}\vert\le 1,\\
0 & \mbox{ otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}$$

Then it turns out that for any $n\not\in X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, $j_n$ is not in the clone generated by $\{j_m:m\in X\}$. This isn't true of the $f_n$s above, since we can define e.g. $f_2$ in terms of $f_5$: $$f_2(x,y)=f_5(x,x,x,x,y).$$ Besides proving that the clone generated by the $j_n$s is not finitely generated, this also gives a proof that there are continuum-many clones on a three-element set. *(Of course this is well-known, but it seems weirdly hard to find a proof online.)*

---

EDIT: Note that each of the size-continuum family of clones constructed above is missing lots of of constant functions. A natural question is whether there are continuum-many clones on a three-element set each of which contains every constant function. This question was posed by McKenzie, and answered affirmatively by [Agoston/Demetrovics/Hannack](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444877598500067). Generally, my understanding is that the lattice of clones on a three-element set is generally considered too complicated to describe fully, with *most* clone properties that don't obviously force countability occurring continuum often, but somewhat contra that theme see [Csakany](http://acta.bibl.u-szeged.hu/12355/1/cybernetica_006_numb_003_227-238.pdf).