# Lattices of clones: is $4$ worse than $3$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

For finite $k$, let $\mathscr{C}_k$ be the set of [clones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(algebra)) on a $k$-element set, viewed as a metric space by setting $d(A,B)=2^{-n}$ for distinct clones $A,B$ where $n$ is the smallest number such that the $n$-ary parts of $A$ and $B$ are different. Note that [$\mathscr{C}_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_lattice) is countable but $\mathscr{C}_k$ has cardinality continuum as soon as $k>2$; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663231/is-there-a-clone-on-a-three-element-set-which-is-not-finitely-generated/4664400#4664400) for an easy proof of the latter fact.

> **Question**: Is there a continuous (or even [Lipschitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)) function $m:\mathscr{C}_4\rightarrow\mathscr{C}_3$ which is a lattice embedding, that is, satisfies $A\subseteq A'\iff m(A)\subseteq m(A')$?

*EDIT: per [Keith Kearnes' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4725979/28111), this may be over-ambitious - it's not even clear whether there is a lattice embedding $\mathscr{C}_4\rightarrow\mathscr{C}_3$ at all.*

There is certainly such a map in the other direction: given a clone $A$ on $\{1,2,3\}$, consider the new clone $B$ on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ whose $n$-ary functions are those $f$ satisfying $$f(x_1,...,x_n)=g(\min\{3,x_1\}, ...,\min\{3,x_n\})$$ for some $n$-ary $g\in B$. Basically, we just "treat $4$ as $3$." An $n$-ary difference between $A$ and $A'$ gets converted into an $n$-ary difference between the corresponding $B$ and $B'$, so this is in fact $1$-Lipschitz.

*In some sense the question I really want to ask is whether the set of clones on $\{1,...,4\}$ is "structurally more complicated" than the set of clones on $\{1,...,3\}$; this is just one way of trying to make that question precise. Any comments addressing this vaguer question would also be welcome!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***In some sense the question I really want to ask is whether the set of clones on $\{1,\ldots,4\}$ is "structurally more complicated" than the set of clones on $\{1,\ldots,3\}$; this is just one way of trying to make that question precise. Any comments addressing this vaguer question would also be welcome!***

As suggested in the question, "structural complexity" can be measured by maps. One might say that $A$ and $B$ are equally complex from viewpoint $X$ if there are $X$-maps between them in both directions. If identity maps are $X$-maps and compositions of $X$-maps are $X$-maps, this can be reformulated equivalently as: is it true that, for every $C$, there is an $X$-map from $C$ into $A$ iff there is an $X$-map from $C$ into $B$? This suggest that one could study "similarity of complexity" by investigating which objects $C$ have $X$-maps into either $A$ or $B$.

Some work has been done on this, where $A={\mathscr C}_3$, $B={\mathscr C}_4$, and $X$-maps = lattice embeddings = meet and join preserving injections.

It is not hard to see that $A={\mathscr C}_3$ embeds into $B={\mathscr C}_4$,
so any lattice $C$ that embeds into $A$ will also embed into $B$. I don't think anybody knows yet whether there is a lattice embedding of ${\mathscr C}_4$ into ${\mathscr C}_3$. It was shown in

Bulatov, A. A.
Finite sublattices in a lattice of clones.
Algebra and Logic 33, no. 5, 287-306 (1995)

that if $C$ is any countable direct product of finite lattices, then
$C$ is embeddable into $B={\mathscr C}_4$, but it was posed as an open
problem in this paper whether every such $C$ also embeds into
$A={\mathscr C}_3$. If No, then this would provide a sense in which
$B={\mathscr C}_4$ is more complex than $A={\mathscr C}_3$.

Let me mention another result which suggests the possibility that ${\mathscr C}_4$ is more complex than ${\mathscr C}_3$. Let $F_n$ be the free semigroup on $n$ generators. Let ${\mathscr L}_n$ be the **dual** of the lattice of subsemigroups of $F_n$. In

Bulatov, A. A.
Identities in lattices of closed classes.
Discrete Math. Appl. 3 (1993), no. 6, 601-609

it is shown that $C={\mathscr L}_n$ embeds in $B={\mathscr C}_4$ for every $n\geq 1$. It is also shown that $C={\mathscr L}_n$ is embeddable in $A={\mathscr C}_3$ **for $\mathbf{n=1}$**, but it is not known whether $C={\mathscr L}_n$ is embeddable in $A={\mathscr C}_3$ for any $n>1$. If, for example, ${\mathscr L}_2$ does not embed in $A={\mathscr C}_3$, then this would provide a sense in which
$B={\mathscr C}_4$ is more complex than $A={\mathscr C}_3$.

Comment: As always, this is lovely! I'm going to hold off on accepting/bountying for a couple days to see if an answer to the specific question in the OP comes in, but thanks a ton! In particular, I took it for granted that there would be a lattice embedding $\mathscr{C}_4\rightarrow\mathscr{C}_3$ in the first place. Do you know if the "global" lattice embedding question is answered if we replace $4$ by some larger number?