# Is there a finite generating set for the clone of all operations on a finite set with at least 3 elements?

Tags: universal-algebra

Let $S$ be a finite set with at least $3$ elements, and let $O(S)$ be the set of all finitary operations on $S$. That is, it is the set of all unary, all binary, all ternary, etc operations collected in one big set. Does there exist a finite set of operations such that the clone generated by that set is $O(S)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **yes**, and in fact $O(S)$ can be generated by a single binary function. For example, in [1936 Webb proved](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2371067?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) that the function $$(x,y)\mapsto [\min\{x,y\}+1]_{\mbox{mod } \vert S\vert}$$ generates the whole clone $O(S)$. See also [Webb's thesis](https://thesis.library.caltech.edu/1457/3/Webb_dl_1936.pdf) and [this hsmse question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5680/who-is-donald-l-webb), as well as [Graham 1967](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Eronspubs/67_02_truth.pdf).

More generally, there is a wealth of information about such topics in Lau's book [*Function algebras on finite sets*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-36023-9), although it can be a bit tricky to navigate. Note that your $O(S)$ is Lau's $P_{\vert S\vert}$.

---

There is an important (if elementary) caveat here: since [there are uncountably many clones on a finite set with $>2$ elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663231/is-there-a-clone-on-a-three-element-set-which-is-not-finitely-generated/4664400#4664400), it is **not** the case that "big = complicated" for clones: a subclone of a $1$-generated clone need not be finitely generated. Of course there is no reason to be surprised by this, but it's still worth mentioning.